# Open (i.e. go to) specific segue from UITabBarController (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, swift2

[image: Sample Image]

In Swift 2, Xcode 7.1

As the image above, `TabBarController` will be the main view. Anonymous user can go to the home tab, if they click on the "Me" (Profile) tab, I want the app will pop up the new login segue (navigation controller). User need to login 1st before they can go into the "Me" tab.

Currently I have override the `TabbarControllerDelegate` in the TabBarController class, which as below (I use Parse, so `user = PFUser.currentUser()`, Parse will cache the user):

```
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {


    if (viewController is MeViewController && user == nil) {

        print("login \(viewController)")

        // How could I go to the Login Segue from here?

        return false

    } else {
        return true
    }
}
```

How could I achieve my goal from here? Or any better advice? Btw, I am not able to use `performSegueWithIdentifier` with the `TabBarController` class unless I use it within the `ProfileViewController` class (UIViewController) to achieve it. But if I did that, the app will display the view in 'Me' Tab first then go to the 'Login' segue, which is not what I wanted

It will be great thanks for any advices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user to not be able to go to me before login, you can just do a check with a static bolean which will be initialize in app delegate.
Then if the bolean is set to false (default value), you can invoke the your login popup.
No point here to perform a segue, just put an identifier on the view in the storyboard (identity inspector => storyboard id) and then you can invoke this particular view of the storyboard like this :

```
let SB = UIStoryboard(name: "MyStoryboard", bundle: nil)
let controller = SB.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyId")
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Segues are only for views which are linked to each other, i personnaly almost never used them.

Comment: This is the brilliant answer, it's correct that the storyboard will be much better than a segue, so I gave the vote to you. But as I never thought in this way to solve the problem (as a newbie), and Santa's answer will 100% fit for my question (as what I asked), so I gave the bounty to him. Hope you guys don't mind. Both of you guys gave me a lot of excellent experiences in iOS development, great thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

I recommend that you make the login `UINavigationController` segue come directly from the `UITabBarController` instead of on the "Me" controller. This is because you can't modally present your login controller through the "Me" controller if its not on the screen.

Give the segue an identifier (eg. `"my-identifier"`):

- Click on the segue in the storyboard editor and fill in the identifier field in the right sidebar.

After this is configured correctly, the following code will perform the login segue (note the use of `tabBarController` since you should have the segue configured from the `UITabBarController`:

```
tabBarController.performSegueWithIdentifier("my-identifier", sender: self)
```

Comment: It works & the most important thing is you did clearly explain where the problem is. You are right, I can't present something that's not on the screen. That's why I try performSegueWithIdentifier before in the NavController, but Xcode told me that I link to wrong parent controller. I'd better read more about the VC docs as a newbie. Great thanks for help :D

Comment: @Neaped Glad to be of help! Don't forget to award the bounty (click the +50 to the left of the answer) if this answer helped you and you're not seeking any more information.